# PhpStorm Built-In Web Server doesn't work with PHP and cause "No input file specified" error

Tags: php, phpstorm

I just installed "jetbrains PhpStorm 7.1.3" and configured PHP Interpreter (PHP 5.5.14) Properly. But using its built-in web server gets `No input file specified` error in Browser for every php scripts.

how can I get rid of this problem?

my OS is Windows 7 64-bit.

related parts of idea.log:

```
2014-07-26 00:15:37,122 [  57068]   INFO - rains.ide.BuiltInServerManager - built-in server started, port 63342 
2014-07-26 00:15:38,613 [  58559]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/codeStyleSettings.xml file is null 
2014-07-26 00:15:38,628 [  58574]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/projectCodeStyle.xml file is null 
2014-07-26 00:15:40,204 [  60150]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/fileColors.xml file is null 
2014-07-26 00:15:41,577 [  61523]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/IntelliLang.xml file is null 
2014-07-26 00:15:42,528 [  62474]   INFO - dvertisement.PluginsAdvertiser - plugins.jetbrains.com 
java.net.UnknownHostException: plugins.jetbrains.com
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:996)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:975)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:850)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.RepositoryHelper.loadPluginsFromRepository(RepositoryHelper.java:72)
    at com.intellij.openapi.updateSettings.impl.pluginsAdvertisement.PluginsAdvertiser$2$1.run(PluginsAdvertiser.java:249)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:464)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$8.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:373)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:420)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:150)
2014-07-26 00:15:43,106 [  63052]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/phing.xml file is null 
2014-07-26 00:15:49,314 [  69260]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/webResources.xml file is null 
2014-07-26 00:15:51,015 [  70961]   INFO - tor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl - Project opening took 32828 ms 
2014-07-26 00:15:53,963 [  73909]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/cachedDictionary.xml file is null 
2014-07-26 00:16:00,181 [  80127]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/watcherTasks.xml file is null 
2014-07-26 00:18:31,166 [ 231112]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $APP_CONFIG$/dataSources.xml file is null 
2014-07-26 00:18:31,213 [ 231159]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/dataSources.xml file is null 
2014-07-26 00:18:31,244 [ 231190]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/sqlDataSources.xml file is null 
2014-07-26 00:18:31,260 [ 231206]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/jsLibraryMappings.xml file is null 
2014-07-26 00:18:31,587 [ 231533]   INFO - s.impl.stores.FileBasedStorage - Document was not loaded for $PROJECT_CONFIG_DIR$/databaseColors.xml file is null 
2014-07-26 00:18:31,966 [ 231912]   INFO - org.jetbrains.io.BuiltInServer - web server stopped
```

Comment: What `idea.log` file says about it?

Comment: Suggestion: Use a VM. In fact it's better to use a VM in the long run because your development environment should be as close to production environment as possible. And I seriously doubt you're going to deploy a PHP app into a windows server; if you are planning that, please change your plan immediately.

Comment: @populus what's the problem with deploying a PHP application under Windows?

Comment: @DarylGill 1) most of the PHP articles around caters to the linux version of PHP. The difference is not that big, but it *will* cause some tearing out of hair while you try to find out why something isn't working. 2) PHP consistently performs worse on Windows compared to Linux 3) Some extensions don't work properly (APC is an important example) 4) If you can afford a windows server, I would recommend that you further invest into programming in something like Java or .NET, which is a strongly typed language.

Comment: I also personally do not see any advantages of a windows server other than satisfying the "needs" of corporate wigheads on the issue of "support", which Redhat also provides for their distribution of linux; Or if you're deploying a .NET application, which is also do-able on linux (ofcourse Windows would be better in this case, but linux option is there)

Comment: @populus I've developed a variety of systems under Windows, I see no dramatic performance hitches compared to Linux, admittedly yes, it's a pull your hair out experience.. Looking past that, it's no different imho

Comment: @DarylGill Not sure why you don't get performance issues, but using WAMP was still about twice as slow vs loading an entire Linux VM and installing Apache + PHP. Maybe it was simply because of APC not working on windows (in fact it's slower with APC installed), but I recall PHP being faster on a Linux VM even without APC installed. I believe it also has something to do with filesystems, where NTFS is generally slower than EXT3/4 (because of seek times, file fragmentation...etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some struggling with phpstorm, finally I found a way to get rid of this problem.

Simply delete the `php.ini` so that there is no `php.ini` in php folder, then restart phpstorm, result in the built-in web server works fine.

Comment: seems like a mal-configed `php.ini` file, can you check if there if there is a `php.ini` file in `C:\Windows` or `C:\Windows\system32`? And also attach a pastebin (or whatever you use) of the `php.ini` file that you deleted

Comment: @Populus I didn't understand what effect can a `php.ini` file in `C:\Windows` or `C:\Windows\system32` have on this problem!? or even how could it be there!? however, I searched there and there wasn't any. Fortunately I had a copy of that `php.ini` and compared it with `php.ini-development` using a diff tool and there was only two differences: `doc_root = "c:/apache24/htdocs"` and `; extension_dir = "c:/php/ext"`

Comment: This is axactly why I hate PHP on windows... *sometimes* it will use the `php.ini` file in `C:\Windows` or `C:\Windows\system32`. There isn't a clear rule as to when that happens, or which takes precedence, which is why people just avoid having `php.ini` in anywhere but the PHP installation folder. I was asking you incase there were such files in your system, for whatever reason.

Comment: Now, as for the diff... which file had the extra/different lines? Also, some logs from PHP would be nice as well... I understand that you got it working, and if you think that's ok, so be it, and you can ignore what I say. However, you should have a `php.ini` in any case for you to tweak your settings (e.g. increasing memory limit, changing error log settings, enabling/disabling extensions....etc.), you'll eventually need the `php.ini` file. Let me know if you want to continue...

Comment: @Populus Of course my `php.ini` had the extra lines, because I had done it. a note which might help is that I examined replacing `php.ini` file with an exact copy of `php.ini-development` and `php.ini-production` files, in both cases there was no problem and phpstorm's built-in server worked properly. It shows that the problem is exactly on setting `doc_root` in php.ini, noting that 'extension_dir` was commented and I had changed it without uncommenting it.

Comment: @Populus I searched for a log but didn't find any. also I tried to turn error logging on in `php.ini` and doing the problematic experience again, but any log file didn't generated! if you know how to generate a log and where it might be stored, tell me to do that.

Comment: You should just make a copy of either the development of production version of the `php.ini` and use that... I know not knowing why something is broken is frustrating, but I gave up on diagnosing windows-related issues a while ago, so if it works, fine. All I was concerned about was having a `php.ini` file for you to alter settings with.

Answer (score -2):

I met the same problem today.I found that I created the project files in wrong doucument.You should put  php scripts into the ducument under"C:\Apache24\htdocs" which depends on your setting in the httpd.conf(file in C:\Apache24\conf).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Your comment is irrelevant to my answer.

Comment: Is it really ? I suppose the 2 persons who downvoted what you call an answer disagree with you.

Comment: Of course.I spent half a day solving that problem. It's ok to disagree with me, if you have tried. The answer "delete the php.ini" is obviously irrational. php.ini contains the configurations of PHP environment. How could we delete this file? It may work in this problem, but other problems will appear.